Warning: A props object containing a "key" prop is being spread into JSX in BottomNavigation.Bar
Get this Error running React Native:
 Warning: A props object containing a "key" prop is being spread into JSX
...
  <Touchable key={someKey} {...props} />
    in BottomNavigation.Bar (created by BottomNavigation)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by BottomNavigation)
    in BottomNavigation (created by MaterialBottomTabView)
    in MaterialBottomTabView (created by MaterialBottomTabNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by MaterialBottomTabNavigator)
    in MaterialBottomTabNavigator (created by MyTabs)
    in MyTabs (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in ThemeProvider (created by PaperProvider)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Portal.Host)
    in Portal.Host (created by PaperProvider)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by PaperProvider)
    in PaperProvider (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)


It was working without problems until few days before.
There are any fixes to this Error?
Tried to update libraries, but no change.

show full code of Touchable might be help to find what's going on

researched a little more and found: https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/4401  this is a problem in reac-native-paper.
